# Open source school managment software?

Tags: open-source, python, scheduling

The proprietary school management software that my district uses is horrible; it has been deleting schedules randomly and mixing up my kids schedules. Does anyone know if there is any open source school administration software out there? It needs to be able to track grades, attendance and sort kids schedules.

Comment: Please also add the specific features you are looking for, especially as there are some that are also learning management systems e.g. Moodle

Comment: While I have not implemented/used any myself and I can't make any reocmmendations from experience, your question is if there IS any such software. There obviously [appears to be](https://www.techjockey.com/blog/top-5-open-source-free-school-management-software). I second Z Z's suggestion to make your specific needs more clear if you are looking for a tailored recommendation.

Comment: Did you find anything else? I also came across https://gibbonedu.org/